# Combobox not binding initial value when page first shown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**The Scenario**

I have a `UserControl` which contains a couple of controls, one of which is a `ComboBox`. The `UserControl` is conatined with a `Page`.

The `UserControl` exposes a couple of dependency properties to allow the `Items` and `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to be accessed. These are defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(int?), typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int?)null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
public int? SelectedValue
{
    get { return (int?)this.GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(List<ComboItem>), typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((List<ComboItem>)new List<ComboItem>(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
public List<ComboItem> Items
{
    get { return (List<ComboItem>)this.GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

These are binded to the `ComboBox` control as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=ThisControl}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=ThisControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Where the `UserControl` is named `"ThisControl"`.

Also, in the above, `ComboItem` is a class which contains the definitions for each item, namely two properties called `ID` and `Text`. The idea here is that `ID` is the key that is stored in the database, and `Text` is the user friendly value that is displayed in the list.

When the `Page` containing the `UserControl` is created (using the Constructor), the ComboBox items list is populated with the following code:

```
MyComboBox.Items.Clear();
MyComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboItem() { ID = 1, Text = "One" });
MyComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboItem() { ID = 2, Text = "Two" });
```

Finally, the `SelectedValue` is binded to a class property via XML like so:

```
<c:CustomComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyClassInstance.ItemID}" />
```

where the property `ItemID` is of type `int`. It is important to note that the class instance is set *after* the combo box items are populated.

**The Problem**

When the page is first shown, the initial selected value is not set correctly - it is an empty item selection. I can assure that the `ItemID` property is already set to a valid value (i.e. `1`).

When an item is selected from the `ComboBox`, the binding *does* successfully set the `ItemID` property, and is correctly persisted to the database upon a 'save' function.

One strange behavior, which may help to identity the problem, is that if the window containing the `Page` is closed, and then re-opened. The `ComboBox` *does* get th correct initial value - and that is regardless of the ComboBox being set on first attempt, or otherwise.

So, the question is: Why is the initial value not shown the first time the page is displayed?

Comment: How the `SelectedValue` is related to the Combobox? What happen when it changes? Is it bound with `SelectedIndex` of `Combobox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was doing some refactoring to improve how I populate the ComboBox `Items` and I seem to have stumbled across the solution...

The problem seems to be related to the following piece of code that populates the list items:

```
MyComboBox.Items.Clear();
MyComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboItem() { ID = 1, Text = "One" });
MyComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboItem() { ID = 2, Text = "Two" });
```

The solution is to directly set the `Items` property, rather than to clear it and populate it:

```
MyComboBox.Items = GetMyList();
```

Where `GetMyList()` is returning a `List<ComboItem>` type.